# Oracle - Error at line 4: PL/SQL: SQL Statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to build a trigger for my database and I am getting an error and I suspect it is because of my into clause but I am not getting the reason. I was reading the documentation of it (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm) and there is saying:

> By default, a SELECT INTO statement must return only one row.
>   Otherwise, PL/SQL raises the predefined exception TOO_MANY_ROWS and
>   the values of the variables in the INTO clause are undefined. Make
>   sure your WHERE clause is specific enough to only match one row

Well, at least I am trying to be sure that my where clause is returning one and just one row. Can you give me some advice about it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_ticket
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON V_buyTicket FOR EACH ROW
    declare ticketID number; busy number; seatRoom number;
 BEGIN

     select count(a.id_ticket) into busy , s.freeSeats into seatRoom 
    from assigned a
    inner join show e on (a.id_movie= e.id_movie)
    inner join rooms s on (e.id_room = s.id_room)
    where a.id_session = 1 AND a.id_movie = 1
    group by s.freeSeats;

    if(busy < seatRoom ) then
        ticketID := seq_ticket.NEXTVAL;
        insert into tickets(id_ticket, type, number, cc, store) values(ticketID, :new.type, :new.number, :new.cc, :new.store);
        insert into assigned (id_ticket, id_movie, id_session) values(ticketID, :new.id_movie, :new.id_session);
    else
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No available seats');
    end if;
 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `group by` if you want exactly one row returned:

```
select count(a.id_ticket), sum(s.freeSeats)
into busy, seatRoom 
from assigned a inner join
     show e
     on a.id_movie = e.id_movie inner join
     rooms s
     on e.id_room = s.id_room
where a.id_session = 1 and a.id_movie = 1;
```

An aggregation query without a `group by` always returns exactly one row.  The alternative would be to include an explicit `rownum = 1` in the `WHERE` clause.

My guess is that you conditions are not choosing exactly one room.  You might want to check on the logic.

Comment: I need to make a verification with it in a trigger, so I need to save the value into those variables...and that is my error. But I wonder how to solve it...